# Regular expression for finding tags with attributes but in a unique order

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to find the date and the transaction from an html and idk how to get the html with regex. I tried simple html i found it harder to implement. What im trying to do is find the date with the transactions and put it into a array then print it out in a nice format. Im trying to get certain values from a table from this html. Date's html is (div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;") and transctions are all (td align="right"). Here is the html (https://pastebin.com/L8emba2X)

Ive been just messing around with a lot of different versions of regex and none of them seems to work due to having one date but 4 other transactions to pull per date.

```
$text='/<\s*div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div[^>]>| 
<td align="right">(.+?)<\/td>/m';

preg_match_all($text, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

print_r($matches);
```

Ive used this and only the transactions came out. Also idk how to print out the date with a certain transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that here you might want an expression similar to:

```
<\s*div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;"\s*>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>|<td align="right">(.+?)<\/td>
```

for capturing any char and newlines using `([\s\S]*?)`.

Your attempt is just fine, however, `(.*?)` would not pass the newlines, and these would:

```
([\s\S]*?)
([\d\D]*?)
([\w\W]*?)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qtemzi/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/<\s*div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;"\s*>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>|<td align="right">(.+?)<\/td>/m';
$str = '<td align="left"><div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
    2019.06.04 09:35
</div></td><td>5176</td><td align="right">0.00</td><td align="right">0.00</td><td align="right">5,000.00</td><td align="right">5,000.00</td><td>орлого</td><td>                 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left"><div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
    2019.06.04 09:35
</div></td><td>5024</td><td align="right">5,000.00</td><td align="right">-50.00</td><td align="right">0.00</td><td align="right">4,950.00</td><td>Ухаалаг мэдээ үйлчилгээний хураамж</td><td>                 </td>
</tr><tr>
<td align="left"><div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
    2019.06.14 11:00
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(69) "<div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
    2019.06.04 09:35
</div>"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "
    2019.06.04 09:35
"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "<td align="right">0.00</td>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "<td align="right">0.00</td>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "<td align="right">5,000.00</td>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(8) "5,000.00"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "<td align="right">5,000.00</td>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(8) "5,000.00"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(69) "<div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
    2019.06.04 09:35
</div>"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "
    2019.06.04 09:35
"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "<td align="right">5,000.00</td>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(8) "5,000.00"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "<td align="right">-50.00</td>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(6) "-50.00"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "<td align="right">0.00</td>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "<td align="right">4,950.00</td>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(8) "4,950.00"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(99) "<div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;">
    2019.06.14 11:00
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>"
    [1]=>
    string(52) "
    2019.06.14 11:00
        </tbody>
    </table>
"
  }
}
```

Comment: Honestly i can believe how much you've helped me with this. Thank you ill try to implement it right now. Im terrible with regex.